# How can I get NextJs to serve a localised page?

Tags: next.js

I need to export a static site to AWS S3 from a nextjs project. In order to handle next export I don't have the possibility to use normal internationalisation.

So what I did is to create my blog in English and create a folder /fr/ which contains the same pages translated. It's not a big deal, since it's a presentation website I have 5 pages, and the blog will be in en (not translated).

Currently nextjs is properly detecting the user language, and is sending back to the /fr/ path BUT it's reading from the index instead of reading from /fr/

So my current page is kept in en.

Is there a way to ask nextjs to read from the folder /fr ?

```
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
      reactStrictMode: true,
      i18n: {
        locales: ['en', 'fr'],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
      },
      trailingSlash: true,
      
    }
    module.exports = nextConfig
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some guidance for anyone having the same issue trying to build a static website in multiple languages, for very simple projects. Basically I ended up creating a folder /de/ and translate my pages there, and add a button to send users to the correct site.

It's working well because I have under 10 pages.

Answer (score 0):

Even though NextJS is using /fr/ in the URL it is not using language in `pages` structure to locate the correct page.

If you want to continue with your approach you can use `useRouter` from NextJS in your pages which gives you access to router and from router you can get the active locale (see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#accessing-the-locale-information). Then you can return correct content for given locale.